# How can I check if BASS is playing stream?

Tags: c#, bass.dll

How can I check if BASS is playing stream in C#? I mean, I need something like:

```
        public WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wp = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        if(wp.enabled)
        {
             //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something different
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm going to make simple bool and change it everytime I need.

Answer (score 1):

Use BASS_ChannelIsActive()

Marko.